# Let $L:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ a linear application. Show $\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|L(x)\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Lx\|=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|L(x)\|}{\|x\|}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $L:E\to E$ a linear application where $(E,\|.\|)$ is a normed space (possibly with infinite dimension). Show that$$\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|L(x)\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Lx\|=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|L(x)\|}{\|x\|}.$$

---

**Attempts**

Since $\{\|Lx\|\mid \|x\|=1\}\subset \{\|Lx\|\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}$ we have

$$\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|L(x)\|\leq \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|Lx\|.$$

1) How can I don for the reverse inequality ?

---

Then

$$\frac{\|Lx\|}{\|x\|}=\left\|L\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\|,$$

2) From here, how can I conclude that $$\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Lx\|=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|L(x)\|}{\|x\|} \ \ ?$$
It looks clear, but I can't justify it properly.

Comment: Is $L$ supposed to be a linear map of the space $E$ or an isometry of $(E,||\cdot||)$?

Comment: I think that there is no ambiguity in the statement @zzuussee

Answer (score 0):

1) If $\|x\|\leq 1$, $$\|L(x)\|=\|x\|\left\|L\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\|\leq \left\|L\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\|\underset{y=\frac{x}{\|x\|}}{\leq} \sup_{\|y\|=1}\|L(y)\|.$$
Therefore $$\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|L(x)\|\leq\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|L(x)\|.$$

2) Same strategy.